# Angular UI Router: Automatically redirect to child state of parent state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to automatically redirect to a child state of a parent state using UI-Router.

For example:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  template: '<parent></parent>',
  redirectTo: 'parent.child'
})
.state('parent.child', {
  url: '/child',
  template: '<child></child>'
})
.state('parent.child-two', {
  url: '/child-two',
  template: '<child-two></child-two>'
})
```

Visiting the `parent` state would always redirect you to the `parent.child` state. I want to avoid explicitly defining the `redirectTo` property like this:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  template: '<parent></parent>',
  redirectTo: 'parent.child'
})
```

And instead have some sort of wildcard like so:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: '/parent',
  template: '<parent></parent>',
  redirectTo: 'parent.**'
})
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `redirectTo: 'parent.child'` is not a good solution ?

Comment: Because I might have more than one child, and I would just like it to redirect to the first child.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the proper way to achieve this, but you can add in your parent controller this :

```
$state.go($state.get().filter(function(cState) { return cState.name.indexOf('parent.') === 0 })[0])
```

- you retrieve all states with `$state.get()`
- then you filter the restult to get only state with `parent.` at the beginning of its name and take the first one with `[0]`
- and you go to this state with `$state.go()`